# ArcGIS Server and Oracle SDO Geometry Interop - It Can't Be This Slow

Tags: arcgis-server, oracle-spatial

I have an ArcGIS Map Server Map Service connecting to an Oracle 11G instance via Direct Connect.  There is no need for ArcSDE since our application doesn't need versioning, replication, or any other of the doo-dads that ArcSDE provides.  All we want to do is plot some dots on a map.

The Oracle table(s) have a SDO Geometry column containing only point geometry types.  I have implemented a spatial index, validated geometries, optimized tolerance...etc.  However, the rendering performance of a layer pointing at SDO Geometry column is awful - 15-20 seconds to render 10k points with very simple symbology.  I have actually found that using an event layer using raw x,y values is faster than using SDO geometry columns.

I will admit that I am more knowledgeable of MS SQL and PostGIS - but I've been pretty thorough in making sure I am doing good by Oracle.  I am hoping someone with more experience using Oracle SDO Geometry in their map services can provide more guidance - are there maybe a few gotcha's I'm missing.

**UPDATE (Per Vince's Request):**

Spatial Index SQL:  `CREATE INDEX  ON "SGSDWADM"."SERVICELOCATION"("GEOMETRY") INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX`

USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA row:
[image]

Describe Output:

[image]

Comment: If you're connecting with Direct Connect, you're using ArcSDE.  Are you really using a Query Layer?  Are all 10k points plotted on every map?  *Not* having an index would help a full table scan query.

Comment: I am using a query layer - sorry for wrong terminology.  10k points would only be plotted at full extent.  But even when I am drilled down to only a few points in view - still taking forever to draw...

Comment: Please update the question to include the contents of the USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA row for the table, and the SQL you used to create the spatial index.  DESCRIBE output would be a plus.  Have you measured the query performance of various spatial queries from SQL*Plus?  Have you tried generating traces to review the query plan?

Comment: The geometry metadata isn't very legible, and it's missing the SRID (which would determine if 0.001 was too large a tolerance, or too small).  Point-only tables are supposed to be indexed with "parameters('sdo_indx_dims=2, layer_gtype=point')"

Comment: Vince - you rock.  I am not sure why the SRID does not show in the table, but its set to 4326.  However, changing to the spatial index you suggested offers a huge speed increase.  Now my only issue is that ArcMap crashes when I try to do anything with this query layer.

Comment: 4326 is the Esri GCS_WGS_1984 coordsys.  The equivalent Oracle SRID is 8307.  Without a known geodetic SRID, the 0.001 tolerance is probably being interpreted as 1/1000th of a degree (> 111 meters), not 1/1000th of a meter.  Try fixing the SRID, and see if that addresses the Desktop crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spatial indexes in general, and Oracle's spatial index in particular, tend to work better if single-point and multi-point objects are treated differently.  In this case, that would mean using the PARAMETERS option in the CREATE INDEX command, as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX servicelocation_spx ON servicelocation(geometry)
    INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX 
    PARAMETERS ('sdo_indx_dims=2, layer_gtype=point')
/
```

If you have multiple independent disks, there would likely be benefit to specifying
a tablespace on a drive other than the tablespace where the primary table lives
(also inside the PARAMETERS option).

Here's an [Oracle documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_index_query.htm).